# Tizen webapp Geolocation

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

This is my code

> var myCallbackInterval = 240000; 
>   var mySampleInterval => 10000;
>
> function onchangedGPS(info) {     for (var index = 0; index <
>   gpsInfo.length; index++) {        alert("latitude: " +
>   gpsInfo[index].latitude);     } }
>
> function onerrorGPS(error) {
>       console.log('Error occurred. Name:' + error.name + ', message: ' + error.message); }
>
> tizen.humanactivitymonitor.start('GPS', onchangedGPS, onerrorGPS,
>   option);

The only value i receive from latitude is 200... why?

Comment: if this is on emulator you can adjust returned value in emulator control panel.

Answer (score 0):

One confirmation regarding this function

function onchangedGPS(info) { for (var index = 0; index < gpsInfo.length; index++) { alert("latitude: " + gpsInfo[index].latitude); } }

Are you accessing the values from "info" mentioned in the signature.
Since "gpsInfo" is mentioned inside, while accessing..